# Exact numerical answer

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Here is a result I get:

(-0.00012038 - 5.13719*10^-6 I) Derivative[1][Re][
  0.0031338[VeryThinSpace]- 0.0000246409 I]

Why don't I get just one number as a response? What am I doing wrong? I tried N, Simplify and it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that `Re` can't be differentiated. What code did you execute to get this result?

Comment: Could you explain to me why differentiation of real part cannot be done.

Comment: I have an expression a+I b. Is it possible to declare a and b real so that Re[a+Ib] be equal to a and Im[a+I b] be equal to b.

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand` e.g., `ComplexExpand[{Re[a + I b], Im[a + I b]}]`